# python mysql insert into error

Tags: python, mysql

I`m currently working on a scraper in python which collects emergency services announcements from a RSS feed. At the point where I want to add a announcement to my MySQL database I got a strange error. I can't find anything about it. It is about this part:

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO meldingen(melding_title, melding_description, melding_category, melding_region, melding_location, melding_zipcode, melding_emergency, melding_date) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
        uniqueRows.append(hash)
        #print uniqueRows


        # Execute the SQL command
        cursor.execute(sql,(str(title), str(description), str(category), str(region), str(location), str(zipcode), str(emergency), date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
        # Commit your changes in the database
        conn.commit()
```

I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Nicky/Documents/alarmeringen/P2000Scraper.py", line 83, in 
>       cursor.execute(sql,(str(title), str(description), str(category), str(region), str(location), str(zipcode), str(emergency), date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 220, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorvalue
>   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "Erreur de syntaxe pr\xe8s de 'p 2 stank soort lucht: koolmonoxide/co vk: 6 troelstrakade dhg 7630'', ''Brandwe' \xe0 la ligne 1")

I don't understand this whole error. If someone could help it would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quote placeholders when using the Python driver. It'll add the quotes for you. `'%s'` should be `%s` in each case.

See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your `SQL` query. It even says so in the error you provided.

`"INSERT INTO meldingen(melding_title, ....)` should be `"INSERT INTO meldingen (melding_title, .....)` (note the space between the table's name and the parenthesis).